# Calculating number of days given date in UNIX

Tags: date, unix, ksh, csh

I have tried to calculate number of days from January 1st to given date in same year.
Option -d for UNIX command isn't working

```
date -d
date: illegal option -- d
Usage: date [-u] [+format]
       date [-u] [mmddhhmm[[cc]yy]]
       date [-a [-]sss.fff]
```

I'm using this [script](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/4870-days-elapsed-between-2-dates-post16559.html?s=#post16559) but is too long.
Is there a simple way to calculate a nuber of days?

**EDIT**
Result of a script:

```
$ ksh datecalc -a 2013 2 5 - 2013 1 1
$ 35
```

Comment: is `date '+%j'` helpful?

Comment: Older/vendor unix systems don't always support the `-d` option, as the usage message you receive back seems to indicate. You may find that the gnu-date utility which does support `-d` is installed in an alternate directory. Might help to add a tag for which Unix you are using. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

OK so this may be a bit far fetched, but mysql client (or other DB clients) can come in handy for this as they have reliable and well documented date functions.

```
$ mysql ..... --silent -e "select datediff('2013-02-05', '2013-01-01') from dual;"

35

$
```

where ..... are your connection options.

Comment: I'm using Informix database. I have solved it with this: (http://www.prolifics.com/docs/panther4.6/html/dev_html/progjpl.htm#247139)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Perl installed, you can do:

```
perl -MPOSIX=strftime -le 'print strftime("%j",localtime)'
```

For a specific day, e.g. Feb 5:

```
perl -MPOSIX=strftime -le '
    @d=(2013,2,5); 
    print strftime("%j",0,0,0,$d[2],$d[1]-1,$d[0]-1900)
'
```

```
036
```

Comment: I have perl v5.6.1 installed on my machine but, when I run command result is: perl: Command not found. When I run script result is: syntax error at number_of_days.pl line 7, near "-le"
Execution of number_of_days.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @Cikson: What is in number_of_days.pl?  The `-le` is specified as a command-line option, not within a perl script.

Comment: type -a perl
/bin/type[6]: whence: A specified flag is not valid for this command.